# How to reassign all of a user's bugs to another user?

Tags: bugzilla

An engineer just left the team, and I need to reassign his bugs to another person.

We're using Bugzilla 4.4, and I can't seem to find any administrative feature that allows me to reassign bugs between users.  Is this not possible?  I'd rather not have to manually edit each individual bug!

Answer (score 0):

I found it.  Do an advanced search where you are able to specify filtering by Bug Assignee.  At the search results, the bottom of the page contains a link to *Change Several Bugs at Once*.  Click on that link to enable a checkbox in each result row.  At the bottom of the new list, press the *Check All* button.  Now change the Assignee and press Commit.